# Type 'N[P]' cannot be used to index type 'IComponents<N>'

Tags: typescript, entity-component-system

I trying to realize entity component system pattern in typescript. I have a class for entities where i want to keep components of entity. I want to create independent package for this pattern and use it in my other projects.

This is Entity class where i have an error.

```js
type IComponents<N> = {
  [P in keyof N]?: Component<any, N>;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix
export interface EntityType<N> {
  id: string;
  components: IComponents<N>;
  addComponent(component: Component<any, N>): void;
  removeComponent(componentId: N): void;
  print(): void;
}

export default class Entity<N> implements EntityType<N> {
  readonly id: string;
  components: IComponents<N> = {};

  constructor() {
    this.id = v4();
  }

  addComponent(component: Component<any, N>): void {
    this.components[component.name] = component;
  }

  removeComponent(componentName: N): void {
    delete this.components[componentName];
  }

  print(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this, null, 4));
  }
}
```

In the method `addComponents` i got this error
`Type 'N' cannot be used to index type 'IComponents<N>'.`

This is signature for the `Component` class

```js
export default abstract class Component<P, N> {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly name: N;
  props: P;

  protected constructor(props: P, name: N) {
    this.props = props;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = v4();
  }
}
```

There is a project where i use this package:

Creating component, entity and enum for components

```js
export enum EComponents {
  position,
}


export default (): Entity<EComponents> => {
  const player = new Entity<EComponents>();
  player.addComponent(new PositionComponent());

  return player;
};
```

System which take an entity and handle it. In this method i want take from `entity.components` specific component and handle it

```js
 update(entity: Entity): void {
    const component: PositionComponent | null = this.getComponent(entity);

    if (!component) return;

    const { x = 0, y = 0 } = component.props;
    const position = { x, y };

    if (this.keyboard.isKeyPressed('KeyW')) {
      position.y -= 3;
    }

    if (this.keyboard.isKeyPressed('KeyA')) {
      position.x -= 3;
    }

    if (this.keyboard.isKeyPressed('KeyS')) {
      position.y += 3;
    }

    if (this.keyboard.isKeyPressed('KeyD')) {
      position.x += 3;
    }

    entity.components['Position'].props = position;
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your `N` and `P` naming convention. `P` is some property type, and `N` is some name type, right?  So I'd expect `N` to be stringlike itself.  But you've got a lot of `keyof N` going around, so I'm not sure.  Anyway you get an error because you are trying to use `N` as an index to something whose keys are `keyof N`, not `N`.  You need to fix that discrepancy.  I don't know how to tell you to do that, though, since I really don't understand the intent of the code.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, P is some properties, and N it is enum where keep names of components. I want to get list of components from field `components` in Entity class.

Comment: Can you add the code for your enum and how you plan to use the `Entity` class and call its methods?  (that is, can you post a [mcve]?)  You are probably confusing the enum *values*, whose type `Enum` is a union of numbers or strings with the enum *object*, whose type `typeof Enum` is a mapping from names to those numbers or strings.  If `N` is the enum value type, then you don't want to use `keyof N`.  On the other hand, if `N` is the type of the enum object, then you don't want to use `N` as an index.  In `addComponent` you seem to be doing both things, and it's an error.

Comment: Thank you for attention. I updated my question, added more code examples.

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Please familiarize yourself with those guidelines so you can increase the chance of getting a good answer.   A *minimum* reproducible example also means *removing* code from your question unless it directly relates to your problem.  And a minimum *reproducible* example means anyone else should be able to drop the code into an IDE and see the same issue you're seeing, without having unresolved 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: My *guess* here is that maybe you should change `type IComponents<N> = { [P in keyof N]?: Component<any, N>; }` to something like `type IComponents<N extends keyof any> = { [P in N]?: Component<any, N>;}` ( keeping in mind that you might need to constrain other uses of `N` to `keyof any`.) But this is just a guess, because I cannot test the code without a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/html5game-e68f0 - i created `reprex`, but i couldn't start it. Thank you. This is little bit help, but `entity.components.position` haven't documentation from ide. I think about to change my mind about my problem, because i don't see exit from it

Comment: I'm not sure how to help further unless you make your examples *minimal*, removing anything not directly related to your problem.  And you now seem to be asking about a different problem (missing IntelliSense hinting or something).

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. I found the answer for me, thanks to you for that. If you interested in my problem i'll write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two types `IComponents` and `IMappedComponents`. `IComponents` for list of components which extends from `Component`. And second type `IMappedComponents` for list of components for object in `Entity`.

```js
export type IComponents<N extends keyof any> = {
  [P in N]?: Component<any, N>;
};


export type IMappedComponents<N extends keyof any, C extends IComponents<N>> = {
  [P in N]?: C[P];
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix
export interface EntityType<N extends keyof any, C extends IComponents<N>> {
  id: string;
  components: IMappedComponents<N, C>;
  addComponent(component: C[N]): void;
  removeComponent(componentId: N): void;
  print(): void;
}

export default class Entity<N extends keyof any, C extends IComponents<N>> implements EntityType<N, C> {
  readonly id: string;
  components: IMappedComponents<N, C> = {};

  constructor() {
    this.id = v4();
  }

  addComponent(component: C[N]): void {
    if (component) {
      this.components[component.name] = component;
    }
  }

  removeComponent(componentName: N): void {
    delete this.components[componentName];
  }

  print(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this, null, 4));
  }
}
```